# Need code critique for time interval test script PHP

Tags: php, time, timestamp, intervals

Hey again!  I'm trying to write a set of scripts that will run on a page only if it has been more than 15 minutes since they last ran.  Basically, an automated script updates a database of mine every half hour--and a page which displays that information and updates session variables must obviously query the database whenever it is opened.

So in order to minimize queries but also stay on the safe side, I figured that the session variables would only be updated from the database if it had been more than fifteen minutes since that page was last viewed.  I wrote up some code, and I was hoping you guys could take a look at it before I try implementing it?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['time_next'])){

    $_SESSION['time_next'] = time() + (15 * 60);
                                     //15 minutes   
}
else if(time() >= $_SESSION['time_next']){

    //update all the session variables, etc...

    $_SESSION['time_next'] = time() + (15 * 60);    
}
```

What do you think?  Will this work?

Comment: You know every user has their own set of session data right?  If 100 people view this page, your code would end up running once every 15 minutes for each of them.  If you want to run this exactly once every 15 minutes, you should use something like a database.  Or, even better, just use cron.

Comment: Yeah I figured--which is actually necessary.  This project is something of a web-app, so each user who is using it at the same time needs access to their own particular data from the database.  Based on a series of factors which are different for each user, their data could be displayed differently.

So in essence, yeah the script needs to be updated for each user on their own timetable because each user will be seeing different data.

Comment: Oh actually-sorry, I misunderstood your answer.  Yes, there is already a CRON script on the database which updates it every 30 minutes.  Each INDIVIDUAL USER accesses that data, and it is put into some session variables that are displayed (and used in other pages)--so if they navigate to a different page and then come back, the data could be different at that point.  I'm trying to make it so the database isn't queried EVERY time they come back to that page, just ONLY if its been 15 minutes, because my 30 minute auto-script will most likely not have run in that 15 minute timeframe.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but you can write it shorter and cleaner*. Do note that the session is visitor-bound, so when 10 people request the page, you will get 10 instances running your update.

```
do_update_if_needed(15);

function do_update_if_needed($minutes)
{
    if ( isset($_SESSION['time_next']) && time() < $_SESSION['time_next'] ) return;

    // either time_next was not set, or it's time to update, so set next time:

    $_SESSION['time_next'] = time() + $minutes*60;

    // do your thing!
}
```

You could also write a simple file containing the last time (or using its last-modified time). In general I think it is better to record the *last* time than the *next* time, since the *last* time actually tells something that has happened, not just "a plan" (which leads to questions, like who's plan was it? why? etc.)

*cleaner refers to: 1) put it in a function, and 2) do the calculation in one place, not in two branches of `if`

Comment: Perfect.  Again, I'm definitely aware that the script will run 10 times, but it's pretty critical to the functionality of the app that it do so.

Your code does look much more efficient than mine.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow, actually, yeah-upon closer examination that is WAY nicer than mine.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create [`DAEMONS`](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/) for this sort of thing.

You definitely **should not go the way you're headed** as others have better explained.

You also **should not use cron** because if the process takes more that the time you think it should take it will overun the other process. That could make a mess of you app and it's really not an elegant solution.

A `deamon` will run in the background in a silent fashion. Will deal with all the work-load you need, wont overwrite itself and can also run in a pre-set amount of time.

**[Take a look at this excellent tutorial by Kevin van Zonneveld](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/)**.

Comment: How could I go about installing a daemon if I'm not hosting the site myself?  It definitely seems like the way to go, although the script that is automated every half-hour is extremely simple, and the one that the user accesses every time they load the "dashboard" page only retrieves data for viewing...  I dunno, I think I'm in over my head...

Comment: @user405056 well... maybe you are. Don't over complicate it if you don't need. Just write a mental note about `Daemons` and when a problem does come up that has a high-probability of breaking you'll know the way to go! ;)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose so!  Maybe when my app has 6 billion users and I'm swimming in hundreds of millions of dollars I can figure out a Daemon hahaha!  Anyway, I'll be doing some serious reading--thanks again for your help!